# Can we Draw Text Vertically on Canvas in j2me

Tags: java-me, nokia

I am working on j2me project for nokia N97.I want to write the test vertically i.e rotate my text vertically.I am using Graphics.DrawString(); method to draw text on canvas.

Can any one help me how to draw and rotate text on canvas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mutable `Image` of the size of the text you require (use `Font.stringWidth()` and `Font.getHeight()` for the dimensions), draw the text on to the `Image`'s `Graphics` object, use the image to instantiate a `Sprite`, rotate it using `Sprite.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT90)`, and finally draw it using `Sprite.paint()`.

More info on all of these in the [MIDP2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i was knowing that by taking sprite it is possible.but I was actually asking that if is is been possible by drawtext